# How do you change the music instrument for a MusicTrack?

Tags: ios, audiotoolbox

Using audiotoolbox, I created a MusicSeqence by NewMusicSequence. Then I created a MusicTrack by MusicSequenceNewTrack. I inserted a few notes into the MusicTrack by MusicTrackNewMIDINoteEvent. And I created an AVMIDIPlayer to play the MusicSequence. However, I can play it with only one music instrument: piano. My question is that if it is possible to change the music instrument for a MusicTrack? For example, play a MusicTrack with violin. If it is possible, how do you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

```
var inMessage = MIDIChannelMessage(status: 0xE0, data1: 120, data2: 0, reserved: 0)
MusicTrackNewMIDIChannelEvent(musicTrack!, 0, &inMessage)
// set msb to 120 and lsb to 0

inMessage = MIDIChannelMessage(status: 0xC0, data1: 48, data2: 0, reserved: 0)
MusicTrackNewMIDIChannelEvent(musicTrack!, 0, &inMessage)
// change program to 48
// you changed the instrument to Orchestra Drums
```

And you can get all instruments information from CopyInstrumentInfoFromSoundBank.
The status and its corresponding data1 and data2 for MusicTrackNewMIDIChannelEvent can be found in [here](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Multimedia/node158.html)

Comment: The status of `0xE0` sets the pitch bend, which is **not** what you want. To select the bank, you need two calls with status `0xB0` (Control Change), then the `0xC0` (Program Change) to set the voice in the bank.

Comment: @Ford, according your suggestion, I found this page: [link](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/table-3-control-change-messages-data-bytes-2). Based on that page, before calling '0xC0', I need to input 0 as data1 and MSB as data2 into '0xB0' to set MSB. And then I need to input 32 as data1 and LSB as data2 into '0xB0' to set LSB. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding -- In C, it would be:
`MIDIChannelMessage msg1 = { 0xB0, 0x00, BANKMSB, 0 };
MIDIChannelMessage msg2 = { 0xB0, 0x20, BANKLSB, 0 };
MIDIChannelMessage msg3 = { 0xC0, PROGRAM, 0, 0 };`